# How many rectangles larger than $2 \times 2$ can be made in a $5 \times 5$ grid with a hole in the center?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

### Description

Take a $5 \times 5$ grid with a hole in the center (a vertex *can not* be in this hole), illustrated here:

[image]

For a bit more clarity, the following does work as a valid rectangle, because a vertex is not on the hole.

[image]

But, the following does NOT work as a valid rectangle, because it is only a 2x2 rectangle:
[image]

### Question

How many distinct rectangles following the rules above can fit within this?

Furthermore, for each square within this grid, how many rectangles require it as a vertex?

Each rectangle must be composed of vertical and horizontal lines. Diamonds do not work.

Comment: You sat a vertex cannot be in the hole, and then you say the first example is invalid because no vertex is in the hole.  Which is it?

Comment: +saulspatz I said that it *was* valid. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: There is no restriction mentioned that the sides of the rectangle must be horizontal and vertical?

Comment: +GEdgar For the sake of this question, the rectangle must be horizontal and vertical. I will make that more clear in the question, thank you.

Comment: For future information, in English, "vertice" is not a word. Write "vertex".

Comment: The grid is meant to be 5x5 but in the third image the disallowed rectangle is labelled 2x2. I'm unsure how you are 'counting' units on this grid. Since the vertices appear only at the center of the blocks, it might be simpler to work with the complement of the grid in the diagrams

Comment: Oh yes.  Sorry.  Somehow, I kept reading it as "does *not* work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a rectangle must have height and base at least $2$.

There are $10\times 10$ rectangles total.

Of these the ones that are not larger than $2\times 2$ are only the ones that are $2\times 2%$ and they are $16$.

This means there are $84$ rectangles larger than $2\times 2$.

We just have to substract the ones that contain the center as a vertex. We assume the opposite corner is in the top left. Then there is $3$ options for the oposite corner.

So if we don't assume it is in the top left there are $4\times 3$ options.

Hence there are $84-12 = 72$ rectangles larger than $2\times 2$ that do not have a vertex in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Larger than $2\times 2$ certainly means area $>4$, so area $\ge 5$. As $5\cdot 5>24$, it is not possible to have more than four such rectangles. Obviously, four rectangles of $2\times 3$ work.

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP means for the rectangles to be made simultaneously.  That's not how I read the question, at least.

Comment: The rectangles do not have to cover the board simultaneously.